# Ayuda la funcion unset(), no elimina las variables de $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel

hola espero me puedan ayudar quiero eliminar variables de session especificas, pero no lo hace,  estoy utilizando la función unset, pero mi código no elimina las variables de session tengo dos botones por los cuales dependiendo de cual elijan me disrecciona a un archivo php en el cual están mis dos opciones para eliminar mis variables de session, envió una variable  llamada opción por medio del url de la pagina y el valor que se evaluara en mi archivo php que recibe estas variables pero no lo hace y apsera de que si me muestra el mesaje de que se ejecuto correctamente no se eliminan siguen losdatos en la session, este es el codigo de mi archivo php llamado cancelarCotizacion.php :

```
<?php
$opc=htmlentities($_GET['opcion']);

if ($opc='eliminarAll') {
  // code...
  unset($_SESSION['cnombre'],
  $_SESSION['cPriapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cSegapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cdireccion'],
  $_SESSION['cemali'],
  $_SESSION['Ocupacion'],
  $_SESSION['crfc'],
  $_SESSION['telCliTipo'],
  $_SESSION['clitel'],
  $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);

}else if($opc='eliminarEncargado'){

  unset($_SESSION['cnombre'],
  $_SESSION['cPriapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cSegapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cdireccion'],
  $_SESSION['cemali'],
  $_SESSION['Ocupacion'],
  $_SESSION['crfc'],
  $_SESSION['telCliTipo'],
  $_SESSION['clitel']);
}


header('location:../inicio/index.php');


 ?>
```

y estos son mis dos botones los cuales redireccionan ala misma pagina los dos pero con diferente valor en la variable opcion este s el codigo

```
<a title="Cancelar esta cotizacion" href="../cotizaciones/cancelarCotizacion.php?opcion=eliminarAll"  class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red" ><i class="material-icons">delete_sweep</i></a>


<a title="eliminar datos de encargado" href="../cotizaciones/cancelarCotizacion.php?opcion=eliminarEncargado" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green" ><i class="material-icons">voice_over_off</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente tu problema esta en el `if` y en el `elseif`

```
if ($opc='eliminarAll')
```

Esto deberia ser `if ($opc=='eliminarAll')`, tienes que tener dos signos = para comparar, como tu lo tienes, estas asignado a la variable `$opc` el valor 'elminarAll'

Para el `else if` tambien tienes que poner los dos signos =

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
$opc=htmlentities($_GET['opcion']);

if ($opc=='eliminarAll') {
  // code...
  unset($_SESSION['cnombre'],
  $_SESSION['cPriapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cSegapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cdireccion'],
  $_SESSION['cemali'],
  $_SESSION['Ocupacion'],
  $_SESSION['crfc'],
  $_SESSION['telCliTipo'],
  $_SESSION['clitel'],
  $_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);

}else if($opc=='eliminarEncargado'){

  unset($_SESSION['cnombre'],
  $_SESSION['cPriapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cSegapellido'],
  $_SESSION['cdireccion'],
  $_SESSION['cemali'],
  $_SESSION['Ocupacion'],
  $_SESSION['crfc'],
  $_SESSION['telCliTipo'],
  $_SESSION['clitel']);
}


header('location:../inicio/index.php');


 ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho y de igual forma observe   otro error por el cual no me eliminaba las sesiones también me faltaba incluir el session_start();, gracias saludos. soy nuevo en esto de web y voy comenzando se agradece saludos

Comment: Me alegro de que haya servido mí respuesta, tienes razón no me había fijado que te faltaba session_start().  Dale positivo a mí respuesta y marcarla como correcta. Saludos